# Python dynamic MultiThread with Queue - Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been struggling to implement a proper dynamic multi-thread system until now. The idea is to spin up multiple new pools of sub-threads from the main (each pool have its own number of threads and queue size) to run functions and the user can define if the main should wait for the sub-thread to finish up or just move to the next line after starting the thread. This multi-thread logic will help to extract data in parallel and at a fast frequency.

The solution to my issue is shared below for everyone who wants it. If you have any doubts and questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jul  5 00:00:51 2021

@author: Tahasanul Abraham
"""

#%% Initialization of Libraries

import sys, os, inspect

currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir)
parentdir_1up = os.path.dirname(parentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir_1up)

from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread, Lock

class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, tasks):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.daemon = True
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            func, args, kargs = self.tasks.get()
            try:
                if func.lower() == "terminate":
                    break
            except:                
                try: 
                    with self.lock:
                        func(*args, **kargs)
                except Exception as exception: 
                    print(exception)
            self.tasks.task_done()

class ThreadPool:
    def __init__(self, num_threads, num_queue=None):
        if num_queue is None or num_queue < num_threads:
            num_queue = num_threads
        self.tasks = Queue(num_queue)
        self.threads = num_threads
        for _ in range(num_threads): Worker(self.tasks)
    
    # This function can be called to terminate all the worker threads of the queue
    def terminate(self):
        self.wait_completion()
        for _ in range(self.threads): self.add_task("terminate")
        return None

    # This function can be called to add new work to the queue
    def add_task(self, func, *args, **kargs):
        self.tasks.put((func, args, kargs))

    # This function can be called to wait till all the workers are done processing the pending works. If this function is called, the main will not process any new lines unless all the workers are done with the pending works.
    def wait_completion(self):
        self.tasks.join()
    
    # This function can be called to check if there are any pending/running works in the queue. If there are any works pending, the call will return Boolean True or else it will return Boolean False    
    def is_alive(self):
        if self.tasks.unfinished_tasks == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
        
#%% Standalone Run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    import time
    
    def test_return(x,d):
        print (str(x) + " - pool completed")
        d[str(x)] = x
        time.sleep(5)
        
    # 2 thread and 10000000000 FIFO queues  
    pool = ThreadPool(2,1000000000)
    r ={}
    for i in range(10):
        
        pool.add_task(test_return, i, r)
        print (str(i) + " - pool added")
    print ("Waiting for completion")
    pool.wait_completion()
    print ("pool done")
    
    # 1 thread and 2 FIFO queues
    pool = ThreadPool(1,2)
    r ={}
    for i in range(10):
        
        pool.add_task(test_return, i, r)
        print (str(i) + " - pool added")
    print ("Waiting for completion")
    pool.wait_completion()
    print ("pool done")
    
    # 2 thread and 1 FIFO queues
    pool = ThreadPool(2,1)
    r ={}
    for i in range(10):
        
        pool.add_task(test_return, i, r)
        print (str(i) + " - pool added")
    print ("Waiting for completion")
    pool.wait_completion()
    print ("pool done")
```

**Making a new Pool**
Using the above classes, one can make a pool of their own choise with the number of parallel threads they want and the size of the queue. Example of creating a pool of 10 threads with 200 queue size.

```
pool = ThreadPool(10,200)
```

**Adding work to Pool**
Once a pool is created, one can use that pool.add_task to do sub-routine works. In my example version i used the pool to call a function and its arguments. Example, I called the test_return fucntion with its arguments i and r.

```
pool.add_task(test_return, i, r)
```

**Waiting for the pool to complete its work**
If a pool is given some work to do, the user can either move to other code lines or wait for the pool to finish its work before the next lines ar being read. To wait for the pool to finish the work and then return back, a call for wait_completion is required. Example:

```
pool.wait_completion()
```

**Terminate and close down the pool threads**
Once the requirement of the pool threads are done, it is possible to terminate and close down the pool threads to save up memory and release the blocked threads. This can be done by calling the following function.

```
pool.terminate()
```

**Checking if there are any pending works from the pool**
There is a function that can be called to check if there are any pending/running works in the queue. If there are any works pending, the call will return Boolean True, or else it will return Boolean False. To check if the pool is working or not call the folling function.

```
pool.is_alive()
```

Comment: No, I gave a problem and shared the solution with everyone. Sorry I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.